# Use Shiny widgets on Rmarkdown file: Error in shinyoutput: Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed

Tags: r, shiny, pdf-generation, r-markdown

I would like to print Shiny widgets on a PDF without redefining them on Rmarkdown file (all widgets are already defined on server.R file).

However, I get the message `Error in shinyoutput: Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed.` when I call widgets using "output$widget_name" on Rmarkdown file.

**Please find a reproductible example below**

This is `app.R`

```
 library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(leaflet)
library(rmarkdown)

shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("distPlot"),
  actionButton("report", "Generate report")
 ),


server = function(input, output) {


 output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({

  data <- data.frame(c(1:100), rnorm(100, mean = 0))
  plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~random_y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')

 })

observeEvent(input$report,{ 
  render(input="report.Rmd", output_file= "my_report.pdf")
  system(' open "my_report.pdf"')

  })
}
)
```

This is `report.Rmd`

````
---
title: "Print shiny widgets "
always_allow_html: yes
output:
  pdf_document: default

---




```{r}

library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)
library(plotly)
library(leaflet)

output$distPlot
```
````

Is is possible to achieve it ? 
Thank in advance